# sql query sum by category

Tags: sql

I have a table structure as seen below.
Each tool has a family. Each tool can be related to several families. Each family Can have several tools.

```
| Tool  | Family  | TPT  |
--------------------------------------
| ToolA | FamilyA | TPT1 |
| ToolA | FamilyB | TPT2 |
| ToolA | FamilyC | TPT3 |
| ToolB | FamilyA | TPT4 |
| ToolB | FamilyB | TPT5 |
| ToolC | FamilyB | TPT6 |
| ToolD | FamilyD | TPT7 |
```

I want to sum the TPT column as seen in the results below-

```
| Family  | TPT            |
------------------
| FamilyA | TPT2+TPT3+TPT5 |
| FamilyB | TPT1+TPT3+TPT4 |
| FamilyC | TPT1+TPT2      |
| FamilyD | 0              |
```

Explanation for results- FamilyA has ToolA and ToolB. ToolA is related to FamilyB (TPT2) , FamilyC (TPT3) and FamilyA itself. ToolB is related to FamiltyA itself and FamilyB (TPT5) . So TPT for FamilyA is TPT2+TPT3+TPT5. Same for FamilyB , FamilyC. 
FamilyD is has only ToolD. ToolD is not related to no other family. So TPT for FamilyD is 0. 
How can i write an sql query that will retrieve these results acccording the specified above table structure?

Comment: Have you attempted to write code to solve this issue?

Comment: i need to do it in sql query

Comment: which rdbms? what did you try? what error do you get? did you search SO (via SO-search AND google)? There are tons of this type of question on SO... There should be at least one solving your question.

Comment: I didn't find any and have no idea how to start writing the query

Comment: which rdbms do you use? please give sample data. we are not here to do your work or to guess what you want, but to help you. But only if you give us ALL information, we can help you. please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: additionally there are 2 answers (which may be correct, but are bad, because the don't describe what they are doing). Please add a comment to every answer if you tested it and it did not do what you want. But please FIRST update your question

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work for you as i haven't tested it:

```
SELECT a.family, coalesce(sum(b.tpt), 0) AS total
FROM tbl AS a
LEFT JOIN tbl AS b ON a.tool = b.tool AND a.family != b.family
GROUP BY a.family
```

Comment: Your column names at the top are ambiguous and you'll get a NULL for family D instead of 0, but otherwise looks identical to mine

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the suggestion...  :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one that is a little more precise:

```
SELECT t1.family, coalesce(SUM(t2.tpt),0)
FROM t t1
LEFT JOIN t t2
ON t1.tool = t2.tool
AND t1.family <> t2.family
GROUP BY t1.family
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0dca/7